# Recommend jFrog artifactory/package

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, storage, archive, jfrog-mission-control

We have jFrog service in use, and I'm struggling to chose what type of repository/package I should choose. Please suggest some for my needs. In my release pipeline I'm generating 3 binaries for each OS (Win, Mac, Linux), each has also folder with .json config files, they will be archived(.zip/etc) along with binaries and sent to the artifactory. So what is the best place to store these archives ? (Generic mby ?)
Basically we need to store these archives from releases and have a link, so people could download these archives from repo. Maybe we should not even use artifactory ? Maybe something like CDN or what else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use Generic type. Alternative was S3 Buckets.